# Flipping images from PM to AM time

Tags: java, android, time, viewflipper

I am having set of 8 images. Here the images will be flipping according to the time which is set by the user and their will be default wake up time 7:00am. If the user sets the time at 10:10pm and the wake up time is 7:00am. Now, the images needs to flip and the flipping of images are in percentage wise i.e; 0% 20% 40% 60% 80% 90% 95% 100% of the total time. Now, the images are flipping when i am setting the time from **10:00am to 7:00pm , 9:00am to 11:00am , 7:00pm to 8:30pm etc. But when i am setting from 10:00pm to 7:00am the images are not flipping.**

```
 c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat testhrFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
        SimpleDateFormat testminFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
        String formattedDate = testhrFormat.format(c.getTime());
        int minDate = Integer.parseInt(testminFormat.format(c.getTime()));
        long hrlong = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(Long.parseLong(formattedDate));
        addedmin = hrlong + minDate;
        twwntyhrformat = displayFormat.format(c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
        SharedPreferences timegot = getSharedPreferences("CHILDTIME", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String time = timegot.getString("savedwakeuptime", "");
        try {
            Date date = parseFormat.parse(time);
            String gottime = displayFormat.format(date);
            String[] timedivided = gottime.split(":");
            String gothr = timedivided[0];
            long gotlong = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(Long.parseLong(gothr));
            String gotmin = timedivided[1];
            int gotintmin = Integer.parseInt(gotmin);
            addgottime = gotlong + gotintmin;
            long subtime = addgottime - addedmin;
            String submilli = String.valueOf(subtime);
            long submillitimeunit = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(Long.parseLong(submilli));
            final int gotflippingtime = (int) submillitimeunit;
            handler = new Handler();
            run = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String number = String.valueOf(fliper.getDisplayedChild());
                    if (number.equals("7")) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(run);
                        back_home.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        fliper.showNext();
                        handler.postDelayed(run, gotflippingtime);
                    }
                }
            };
 for (int gotinterval : gotintervals) {
                handler.postDelayed(run, gotinterval);
            }
            handler.postDelayed(run, gotflippingtime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat testhrFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
        SimpleDateFormat testminFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
        String formattedDate = testhrFormat.format(c.getTime());
        int minDate = Integer.parseInt(testminFormat.format(c.getTime()));
        long hrlong = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(Long.parseLong(formattedDate));
        addedmin = hrlong + minDate;
SharedPreferences timegot = getSharedPreferences("CHILDTIME", MODE_PRIVATE);
 long numberlong = timegot.getLong("savedwakeuptime",0);
 long millicurrenttime=TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(addedmin);
        long subtime = numberlong-millicurrenttime;
        Log.d("Calc", String.valueOf(subtime)+"  "+String.valueOf(numberlong)+"  "+String.valueOf(millicurrenttime));
flippingtime = (int) subtime;
        intervals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        intervals.add((int) (flippingtime * 0.20f));
        intervals.add((int) (flippingtime * 0.40f));
        intervals.add((int) (flippingtime * 0.60f));
        intervals.add((int) (flippingtime * 0.80f));
        intervals.add((int) (flippingtime * 0.90f));
        intervals.add((int) (flippingtime * 0.95f));
        intervals.add((int) (flippingtime * 1.00f));
        intervals.add(flippingtime);
        handler = new Handler();
        run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String number = String.valueOf(fliper.getDisplayedChild());
                if (number.equals("7")) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(run);
                } else {
                    fliper.showNext();
                    handler.postDelayed(run, flippingtime);
                }

            }
        };
        for (int interval : intervals) {
            handler.postDelayed(run, interval);
        }
        handler.postDelayed(run, flippingtime);
```

Comment: Check the value of `subtime` in both cases. I suspect that in the second case you get a negative value, since the wakeup time (7am) is smaller than the start time (10pm).

Comment: Yes I am getting the negative value over there. So, what should i do now

Comment: Well, between 10pm and 7am you have 9 hours, so try to figure how to get the right value.

Comment: 10pm to 7am is not a default value the user may set it to 9pm to 7am etc. In your comments made by you yesterday wake up time is smaller than the start time. For this what we should do? we have changed to 24 hours into milliseconds but this one also didn't work.